# NoMethodError (undefined method `charset=' for nil:NilClass): when sending email with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

when trying to send an email with ruby on rails I get following error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `charset=' for nil:NilClass):
```

My code is pretty straight forward (method in Mailer derived from ApplicationMailer):

```
def task_assigned(user)
  @user = user
  @inboxurl = 'http://localhost:4200/main/tasks'
  @referenceurl = 'http://localhost:4200/main/tasks'
  mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Task assigned',template_name: 'task_assigned_email')
end
```

And the view (task_assigned_email.html.erb):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Welcome <%= @user.name %></h1>
  <p>
     a new tasks has been assigned to you.<br>
  </p>
  <p>
    To go to your Inbox, just follow this link: <%= @inboxurl %>.
  </p>
  <p>
    To go to straight to the referenced data, just follow this link: <%= @referenceurl %>.
  </p>
  <p>Have a great day!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I know this was working somewhile ago. I think I did something to stop sending emails so it didnt fill my inbox while testing - but not sure. Did some upgrades in the meantime. Since days I try to figure out what could be the root cause for this issue but the error message doesnt give me any indication. I checked the smtp setting end they look ok too.

Any idea how I can find the root cause? Are there any logs which could help me?

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: I was having the same issue because I was passing a variable into the mailer object's initialisation i.e. `MyMailer.new(something)` - passing the object into the method resolved the issue for me `MyMailer.new.call(something)`

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem and it was because I had given the mailer an initialize method

```
class ReminderMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def initialize
    #stuff
  end
end
```

In my case I didn't really need this so I removed it and things work. If you need initialize, probably need to call super or something...

Comment: I had the same problem and just added to the `initialize` method `super`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try replacing the meta tag
this

```
<meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
```

with

```
<meta content=`text/html`; charset=`UTF-8` http-equiv=`Content-Type` />
```

Comment: Hi, 

yes - doesnt help. I dont think its an issue with the meta data or charset setting. The error is raised because I have an nil reference. So something seems to go wrong within the mail method I call from ApplicationMailer.

Comment: Thas all I get in my log:

    SystemMailer#task_assigned: processed outbound mail in 3.1ms
    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 44ms


  
    NoMethodError (undefined method `charset=' for nil:NilClass):

    app/mailers/system_mailer.rb:48:in `task_assigned_email'
    ...

The rest is the stack of my code which is calling the mailer methiod.

Is there any other log file I can check?

Comment: Looks like it doesn't recognise the charset, remove the meta tag and see.

Comment: Did this already. And I dont think the problem is the charset. The problem is that I have a nil reference. So somthing goes wrong before - and a nil reference has no attribute charset...

Answer (score 0):

change your html file for **task_assigned.html.erb**

Comment: tried that already - doesnt work. I even created a new mailer in my app with the sample from the tutorial. Doesnt work. But it was working some while ago! Something must have happened after I did some upgrades or I applied some wrong settings which cause this issue now.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. Error raised from action_mailer/base.rb #mail method. For me solution was remove old mailer and create new mailer without using Mailer in generator name. like `rails g mailer Tasks task_assigned`